# Loading different data types from XML into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, xml, data-storage

I'm using `cElementTree` to extract xml tags and values in a loop and then storing them into a dictionary.

XML file contains:

```
<root>
    <tag1>['item1', 'item2']</tag1>
    <tag2>a normal string</tag2>
</root>
```

Python code (roughly):

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as xml

xmldata = {}
xmlfile = xml.parse(XMLFile.xml)
for xmltag in xmlfile.iter():
    xmldata[xmltag.tag] = xmltag.text
```

The problem I have encountered is that the xml file contains different data types, which include `string` and `list`. Unfortunately `Element.text` saves all the xml values as `string` (including the lists).

So when I load from the XML file I have:

```
{'tag1':"['item1', 'item2']", 'tag2':'a normal string'}
```

When I'd prefer to have:

```
{'tag1':['item1', 'item2'], 'tag2':'a normal string'}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?
e.g a command that saves to the dictionary in the original format

Or do I need to set up if statements to determine the value type and save it seperately using an alternative to `Element.text`?

Comment: Could you include a complete snippet of code, including the value of xmldata, so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: You might have been able to use `eval`, except that your strings are not surrounded by `'` in the XML.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee You don't ever want to use `eval` on untrusted data (which I assume this is); the string could be something like `'__import__("subprocess").call(("rm", "-rf", "/"))'`.

Comment: @Taymon I know. but it is a possible solution, and in some circumstances (say if it's a once off, personal code, and the definition of what goes into the XML file is known/controlled), it be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use literal_eval to try to parse complex python literals. Since your strigns are unquoted, they will raise a SyntaxError in lteral eval, but that is simle to work around:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as xml
from ast import literal_eval

xmldata = {}
xmlfile = xml.parse(XMLFile.xml)
for xmltag in xmlfile.iter():
    try:
        xmldata[xmltag.tag] = literal_eval(xmltag.text)
    except SyntaxError:
        xmldata[xmltag.tag] = xmltag.text
```

Unlike Python's builtin "eval", ast.literal_eval does not allow the execution of expressions, and thus is safe, even if the XML data come from an untrusted source.

Comment: Thank you, that's handy to know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposed solution: check for the existence of `[`, then parse the list. It's not failsafe (it won't work if the separator is not exactly `,` with a space) but I think that it'll be easy for you to improve it.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as xml

xmldata = {}
xmlfile = xml.parse("data.xml")
for xmltag in xmlfile.iter():
    # it's a list
    if "[" in xmltag.text:
        d = xmltag.text.lstrip("[").rstrip("]")
        l = [item.lstrip("'").rstrip("'") for item in d.split(", ")]
        xmldata[xmltag.tag] = l
    else:
        xmldata[xmltag.tag] = xmltag.text

print xmldata
```

Prints: `{'root': '\n', 'tag1': ['item1', 'item2'], 'tag2': 'a normal string'}`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are not using xml in all its mighty power!

Why don't you organize your `.xml` like:

```xml
<root>
    <tag1>
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
    </tag1>
    <tag2>a normal string<tag2>
</root>
```

This way your python code will be handling every `<tag1>` as a container of `<item>`, and I think that's better.

**Note:** You may also want to take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp). (I agree with the "Favorite Way" of the author)

Comment: Thanks Rik, nice to know I'm on the right track using elements :)